# importing stylizations from other files

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Good evening! I'm new to the stack and have little experience with react and styled-components. I have a styling snippet below that I want to reuse in another part of my code without having to keep typing the same styling commands over and over, how do I do this? I saw a post on how to assemble, but I'm not able to use it in another part of the code.

this code snippet is in a style.jsx file in the helpers folder.

```js
import { css } from 'styled-components';

const mixins = {
  flexCenter: css`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  `,
};

export default mixins;
```

want to repurpose the code above into a part of the code below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { mixins } from '../helpers/style';

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 150px;
  /* ... */
`;
```

I'm going to do the same thing for other parts of the code with other styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse styled components by extending the styles.

```
const mixins = flexCenter: css`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
`;
```

Do the same following:

```
// A new component based on Button.
const PrimaryButton = styled(Button);

// A new component based on Button, but with some override styles
const PrimaryButton = styled(Button)`
      justify-content: center;
    `;
```